# R shiny updateSelectInput in observeEvent not working

Tags: r, shiny

In my Shiny app my users can upload a file from the server to view the results. I have the user select the file using a selectInput, and then they click an actionButton to load the file. I also want users to be able to delete files and add new files, and I've set that up successfully using separate actionButtons. When the user deletes or adds a file I want to update the selectInput so the deleted files aren't there anymore, and the added files are. I tried this using updateSelectInput in my observeEvent code but its not working. Here's my observeEvent for the delete file portion:

```
  #Delete parameter files
  observeEvent(input$delete,{
    file.remove(input$input_file) #deletes the file selected in the input_file widget
    choices <- list.files("C:/Users/shiny/testapp/", pattern="*.Rdata")
    updateSelectInput(session,"input_file",choices) #supposed to update the input_file widget
  })
```

When I run the app with this code in it, two things happen. In the App window, I get this text right above the input_file widget: **[object Object**
And in my R console I get:

> Input to asJSON(keep_vec_names=TRUE) is a named vector. In a future
>   version of jsonlite, this option will not be supported, and named
>   vectors will be translated into arrays instead of objects. If you want
>   JSON object output, please use a named list instead. See ?toJSON.

I have included the `session` parameter in my shinyServer call:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session)
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Try naming your arguments.  `updateSelectInput(session= session, inputId = "input_file", choices = choices)`.  Using positional matching, the third argument in `updateSelectInput` is `label`, so you aren't actually changing the choices, but trying to assign a vector to the `label`.

Comment: That was it! If you put your comment in an answer, I'll check it off.

Answer (score 2):

I found a corner case that also causes this bug. Upon putting `tabPanel()` in a `renderUI()`, an `updateSelectInput` in an unrelated area of my code just stopped working.

To resolve, leave the tabPanel in ui.R, and use `renderUI()` to adjust within the function instead of bringing it all into server.R, like here: [updateSelectInput order of operations/race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29651567/updateselectinput-order-of-operations-race-condition?rq=1)

Comment: Seems like the corner case is true. How do you manage this if you are forced to take everything inside server.R because access to reactive variables are key.
and @hedge did you raise an issue on github? Do the shiny developers know about this?

Comment: not sure. Did not raise an issue.